# How to load the Wikipedia dump?

Tags: python, gensim

I have downloaded dump of Wikipedia files (13.40 GB). It is downloaded in the format `enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2`.

How to load the file in Python & then convert the articles into a plain text file inorder to perform LDA on it?

Was following the instructions fromm https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html but data loading into Python is not mentioned.

Comment: Read Step 2 of the "Preparing the corpus" paragraph on the website you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following code:

```
python -m gensim.scripts.make_wiki filepath
```

where filepath is the filepath for `enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2`.

[<strike>From [gensim: Experiments on the English Wikipedia](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html) &</strike> based on [@Holjer Just's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421705/holger-just) comment]

Comment: I am not able to understand, how does this code converts the data into text file, nowhere I am mentioning which file to convert.

Comment: Also, should i first convert the (.xml.bz2) data into xml file and than apply that code

Comment: "we don’t even need to uncompress the whole archive to disk"  [link](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html) ie. use the `.xml.bz2` file

Comment: I tried this                                                                                               
python -m gensim.scripts.make_wiki("D:\\LDA\\enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2")                                                                                                        gave me error saying invalid syntax, though i have imported gensim as well

Comment: @Deepti try it without the brackets and without the quotation marks.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-14-b7ead8323d4c>", line 1
    python -m gensim.scripts.make_wiki D:\\LDA\\enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2                                                                                                    SyntaxError: invalid syntax (arrow pointing at gensim)

Comment: @Deepti Can you try running it in command prompt instead of the iPython notebook.